# Finding the time spent by id in each location

Tags: pandas, google-bigquery

I am trying to find out how long each id spent time in the starting location.

For example, in the below dataset, starting Geohash of id 286 is "abcdef". Geohash "abcdef" appears in 3 places for the Id 286. 
Hence total time spent by Id 286 is the total of (2017-02-13 12:33:02.063 UTC - 2017-02-13 12:24:36 UTC) and (2017-02-13 12:34:29 UTC - 2017-02-13 12:33:08 UTC).

```
        Id         DateTime                      Latitude     Longitude   Geohash
      0 286        2017-02-13 12:24:36 UTC       40.769230  -73.01205     abcdef
      1 286        2017-02-13 12:33:02.063 UTC   40.769230  -73.01202     abcdef
      2 286        2017-02-13 12:33:05.063 UTC   40.769230  -73.01202     cvzvvv
      3 286        2017-02-13 12:33:08 UTC       40.769280  -73.01212     abcdef
      4 286        2017-02-13 12:34:29 UTC       40.769306  -73.01207     hsffds
      5 368        2017-02-13 00:23:07.063 UTC   33.392820  -111.8262     weruio
      6 141        2017-02-13 00:00:41 UTC       33.287117  -111.84150    oqruqq
```

Not sure whether there is any function in pandas dataframe that achieves this operation.

Any help would be really appreciated. !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  Id, Geohash, MIN(DateTime) AS StartDateTime, SUM(TimeSpent) AS TimeSpent
FROM (
  SELECT 
    Id, Geohash, DateTime, 
    TIMESTAMP_DIFF(LEAD(DateTime) OVER(PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY DateTime), DateTime, SECOND) AS TimeSpent,
    FIRST_VALUE(Geohash) OVER(PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY DateTime) AS FirstGeohash
  FROM yourTable
)
WHERE Geohash = FirstGeohash
GROUP BY Id, Geohash
```

You can test it with dummy data from your example:

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH yourTable AS (
  SELECT 286 AS Id, TIMESTAMP '2017-02-13 12:24:36 UTC' AS DateTime, 40.769230 AS Latitude, -73.01205 AS Longitude, 'abcdef' AS Geohash UNION ALL
  SELECT 286, TIMESTAMP '2017-02-13 12:33:02.063 UTC', 40.769230, -73.01202, 'abcdef' UNION ALL
  SELECT 286, TIMESTAMP '2017-02-13 12:33:05.063 UTC', 40.769230, -73.01202, 'cvzvvv' UNION ALL
  SELECT 286, TIMESTAMP '2017-02-13 12:33:08 UTC', 40.769280, -73.01212, 'abcdef' UNION ALL
  SELECT 286, TIMESTAMP '2017-02-13 12:34:29 UTC', 40.769306, -73.01207, 'hsffds' UNION ALL
  SELECT 368, TIMESTAMP '2017-02-13 00:23:07.063 UTC', 33.392820, -111.8262, 'weruio' UNION ALL
  SELECT 141, TIMESTAMP '2017-02-13 00:00:41 UTC', 33.287117, -111.84150, 'oqruqq'
)
SELECT 
  Id, Geohash, MIN(DateTime) AS StartDateTime, SUM(TimeSpent) AS TimeSpent
FROM (
  SELECT 
    Id, Geohash, DateTime, 
    TIMESTAMP_DIFF(LEAD(DateTime) OVER(PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY DateTime), DateTime, SECOND) AS TimeSpent,
    FIRST_VALUE(Geohash) OVER(PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY DateTime) AS FirstGeohash
  FROM yourTable
)
WHERE Geohash = FirstGeohash
GROUP BY Id, Geohash
```

Result is as below

```sql
Id  Geohash     StartDateTime           TimeSpent    
286  abcdef     2017-02-13 12:24:36 UTC       590    
368  weruio     2017-02-13 00:23:07 UTC      null    
141  oqruqq     2017-02-13 00:00:41 UTC      null
```

Please note: above 590 is a sum of timespent (in seconds) on three pages - not  just on two pages as it is stated in your question - I assume this is just typo on your side

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want something like this:

```
def timedelta(df):
    df = df.sort_values(by='DateTime')
    return df.iloc[0]['DateTime'] - df.iloc[-1]['DateTime']

df.groupby(['Id', 'Geohash']).apply(timedelta)
```